# Difference between closures and normal functions

Tags: javascript, closures, lexical-closures

I was going through the closures definition in Mozilla and found this example -

```
function makeSizer(size) {
  return function () {
    document.body.style.fontSize = `${size}px`;
  };
}

const size12 = makeSizer(12);
const size14 = makeSizer(14);
const size16 = makeSizer(16);
```

What I still don't understand is that if I want to increase the font, I can still do it this way -

```
function makeSizer(size) {
  document.body.style.fontSize = `${size}px`;
}

const size12 = makeSizer(12);
const size14 = makeSizer(14);
const size16 = makeSizer(16);
```

What is the concept of closures doing here? Why the extra inner function?
Please correct my understanding.

Comment: With your code, `size12` and the others are all `undefined`. The closure code assigns the returned functions to those variables, `size12()` can be run over and over again. (I acknowledge that it's not the most interesting example.)

Comment: The first one return the inner function (unexecuted) to the variable. then you can do `size12()` to run it.

Comment: Better examples would perhaps mention Array methods like `.filter()` and `.map()`, which take functions as arguments. A "function maker" function like your sample from MDN can make those functions, so that different situations calling for different `filter()` callbacks can easily be accomodated by making new filter callback functions.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that in the first code block, `makeSizer` creates and returns a function that hasn't yet been called. **If** you call it, it will apply the given `size` to the element. (And if you don't call it, it won't.) In contrast, your rewrite supplies the size to use directly and does the work immediately.

I think it may be clearer if we use the classic example, which is a bit simpler (see comments):

```js
function makeAdder(addend) {
    return function (value) {
        return value + addend;
    };
}

// Let's make a function that will add 6 to whatever value we give it
const add6 = makeAdder(6);

// At this point, we haven't *called* the adder, we've just created it

// Let's call it:
console.log(add6(7));   // 13
console.log(add6(2));   // 8
console.log(add6(36));  // 42
```

This related question's answers may also be useful: [*How do JavaScript closures work?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Answer (score 1):

The function closures the `size` variable, so when you call the returned function the value of `size` will be the same as you gave it to the `makeSizer` function. Without closuring, `makeSizer` returns undefined and cannot be reused.

```js
function makeSizerClosure(size) {
    return function () {
        document.body.style.fontSize = `${size}px`
    }
}

const size12c = makeSizerClosure(12)
const size14c = makeSizerClosure(14)
const size16c = makeSizerClosure(16)

size12c() // size12c sets fontSize to 12, cause it knows the size value as it's closured

function makeSizer(size) {
    document.body.style.fontSize = `${size}px`
}

const size12 = makeSizer(12)
const size14 = makeSizer(14)
const size16 = makeSizer(16)

// you can't even run it cause it's undefined
size12() // error: size12 is not a function
```